# Click event not firing before form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to implement click event on click of submit button but sometimes it is firing before form submission and sometimes it does not work and form is submitted before click event.
How I can trigger this click event every time.
Here is code for this click event

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#addbtn").click(function(){

  });
});
```

Comment: Share the HTML and I would recommend you to use <FORM> submit event handler

Comment: Okay i will add this html in my question right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger an event on HTML element programmatically using [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method. Below, when the `<form>` is submitted, the click event is triggered on the submit button.

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  $(event.target).find("button[type='submit']").trigger("click");

});

$("button").on("click", function(event) {

  console.log("Button clicked");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the trigger method to fire an event from another event

```
("button").on("click",()=>{
  alert("button clicked")
  if($("form").trigger("submit")){
    alert("form submited")
  }
})

<form>
  <input type="text"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

here is the code pen so you can test

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzoJJy